# Ajax jQuery on success how to get the result value passed by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How I can get the success (data) value on Ajax? I want to get the value of firstname and lastname, which are Kevin Yam.

Example I want to set input value, `document.getElementById("reply").value = "Kevin Yam"`

**Ajax code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'getuser_reply_name.php',
    data:{get_reply_postid:post_id,get_reply_commentid:comment_id},
    cache:false,
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

**getuser_reply_name.php code:**

```
if($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($user_firstname, $user_lastname);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            $userdetails = array(
                'u_firstname' => $user_firstname,
                'u_lastname' => $user_lastname
            );

            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($userdetails);
        }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

**Console log result:**

[image]

Comment: in success loop through the response and use the key to get the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Add `dataType:"JSON",` in your `$.ajax`, so that it automatically parse `json` data coming from `php`.

2.Inside `success` fetch data from response using `keys`(what you are seeing in `console.log()`)

Do like below:-

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'getuser_reply_name.php',
    data:{get_reply_postid:post_id,get_reply_commentid:comment_id},
    dataType:'json', //add dataType
    cache:false,
    success: function (data){
        $("#reply").val(data.u_firstname+' '+data.u_lastname); // put value to input box
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is more efficient way to use.

Comment: @TommyChong  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'getuser_reply_name.php',
    data:{get_reply_postid:post_id,get_reply_commentid:comment_id},
    cache:false,
    dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
      encode: true,
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

you will get object of array in response